# Trying to make a graphical Dice Roller and i dont know why the 'shape' is undefined

Tags: python

Im trying to give it the appearance of rolling by making a die appear onscreen waiting a bit then un-drawing it so that another one can appear. I keep getting an error saying that "shape" is not defined. just started coding so dont blast me too hard.

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin ("Rolling Dice", 200,200)
from random import *
import time

win.yUp

def One():
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    middleDot = Circle(Point(105,105), 8)
    middleDot.setFill('black')
    middleDot.draw(win)


def Two():
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    RightDot = Circle(Point(125,125), 8)
    RightDot.setFill('black')
    RightDot.draw(win)
    LeftDot = Circle(Point(85,85), 8)
    LeftDot.setFill('black')
    LeftDot.draw(win)


def Three():
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    midDot = Circle(Point(105,108), 8)
    midDot.setFill('black')
    midDot.draw(win)
    topDot = Circle(Point(105,80),8)
    topDot.setFill('black')
    topDot.draw(win)
    botDot = Circle(Point(105,135), 8)
    botDot.setFill('black')
    botDot.draw(win)

def Four():
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    topleft = Circle(Point(85,85),8)
    topleft.setFill('black')
    topleft.draw(win)
    topright = Circle(Point(125,85),8)
    topright.setFill('black')
    topright.draw(win)
    botleft = Circle(Point(85,125),8)
    botleft.setFill('black')
    botleft.draw(win)
    botright = Circle(Point(125,125),8)
    botright.setFill('black')
    botright.draw(win)

def Five():
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    topleft = Circle(Point(85,85),8)
    topleft.setFill('black')
    topleft.draw(win)
    topright = Circle(Point(125,85),8)
    topright.setFill('black')
    topright.draw(win)
    botleft = Circle(Point(85,125),8)
    botleft.setFill('black')
    botleft.draw(win)
    botright = Circle(Point(125,125),8)
    botright.setFill('black')
    botright.draw(win)
    middleDot = Circle(Point(105,105), 8)
    middleDot.setFill('black')
    middleDot.draw(win)


 def Six():
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    topleft = Circle(Point(85,85),8)
    topleft.setFill('black')
    topleft.draw(win)
    topright = Circle(Point(125,85),8)
    topright.setFill('black')
    topright.draw(win)
    botleft = Circle(Point(85,125),8)
    botleft.setFill('black')
    botleft.draw(win)
    botright = Circle(Point(125,125),8)
    botright.setFill('black')
    botright.draw(win)
    left = Circle(Point(85,105),8)
    left.setFill('black')
    left.draw(win)
    right = Circle(Point(125,105),8)
    right.setFill('black')
    right.draw(win)








Dice = [One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six]

for x in range(1):
     x = randint(1,1)
    if x == 1:
        One()
        time.sleep(.2)
        shape.undraw()
```

Im using python 3.6.3 please help my coding teacher seems to be inept and doesnt seem to actually know how to program anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape variable in your for loop is not global so either you need to make it global or you can put it inside a class:

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin ("Rolling Dice", 200,200)
from random import *
import time

win.yUp
shape = Rectangle(Point(0,0), Point(1,1))

def One():
    global shape
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    middleDot = Circle(Point(105,105), 8)
    middleDot.setFill('black')
    middleDot.draw(win)


def Two():
    global shape
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    RightDot = Circle(Point(125,125), 8)
    RightDot.setFill('black')
    RightDot.draw(win)
    LeftDot = Circle(Point(85,85), 8)
    LeftDot.setFill('black')
    LeftDot.draw(win)


def Three():
    global shape
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    midDot = Circle(Point(105,108), 8)
    midDot.setFill('black')
    midDot.draw(win)
    topDot = Circle(Point(105,80),8)
    topDot.setFill('black')
    topDot.draw(win)
    botDot = Circle(Point(105,135), 8)
    botDot.setFill('black')
    botDot.draw(win)

def Four():
    global shape
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    topleft = Circle(Point(85,85),8)
    topleft.setFill('black')
    topleft.draw(win)
    topright = Circle(Point(125,85),8)
    topright.setFill('black')
    topright.draw(win)
    botleft = Circle(Point(85,125),8)
    botleft.setFill('black')
    botleft.draw(win)
    botright = Circle(Point(125,125),8)
    botright.setFill('black')
    botright.draw(win)

def Five():
    global shape
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    topleft = Circle(Point(85,85),8)
    topleft.setFill('black')
    topleft.draw(win)
    topright = Circle(Point(125,85),8)
    topright.setFill('black')
    topright.draw(win)
    botleft = Circle(Point(85,125),8)
    botleft.setFill('black')
    botleft.draw(win)
    botright = Circle(Point(125,125),8)
    botright.setFill('black')
    botright.draw(win)
    middleDot = Circle(Point(105,105), 8)
    middleDot.setFill('black')
    middleDot.draw(win)


 def Six():
    global shape
    shape = Rectangle(Point(150,150), Point(60,60))
    shape.draw(win)
    topleft = Circle(Point(85,85),8)
    topleft.setFill('black')
    topleft.draw(win)
    topright = Circle(Point(125,85),8)
    topright.setFill('black')
    topright.draw(win)
    botleft = Circle(Point(85,125),8)
    botleft.setFill('black')
    botleft.draw(win)
    botright = Circle(Point(125,125),8)
    botright.setFill('black')
    botright.draw(win)
    left = Circle(Point(85,105),8)
    left.setFill('black')
    left.draw(win)
    right = Circle(Point(125,105),8)
    right.setFill('black')
    right.draw(win)

Dice = [One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six]

for x in range(1):
     x = randint(1,1)
    if x == 1:
        One()
        time.sleep(.2)
        shape.undraw()
```